# Galois Theory Aut(L|K) $\subset S_n$ or $C_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm attempting to show that for $L$ the splitting field of a degree $n$ polynomial $p(x)\in K[x]$ we have that $Aut(L|K)\subset S_n$ or $C_n$ where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$. I can show the first part but I'm not sure how to go about proving the group $Aut(L|K)=C_n$. Is it implied since there is an element of $S_n$ of order $n$? Any hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: if you have to prove "$A$ or $B$" and you have proved $A$, you don't have to prove $B$.

Comment: Is there an example of where $Aut(L|K)=C_3$?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is. Take K to be $ Q(w)$ where $w$ is a cube root of unity  and L the splitting field of $X^3-2$ Then the Galois group of this polynomial is $C_3$